# Stroustrup chapter 4 exercise 6: Improve efficiency

Tags: c++, string, vector, performance

The exercise asks for a code which can convert the user input of the numbers 0-9 either as an integer or string to a string or integer respectively i.e. if`0` is entered `"zero"` will be outputted and vice versa.

```
string number;

cout << "Let's convert strings to numbers."
     << "Enter value/string of 0-9";

while (number!= "exit")
{
    cin >> number;

    for (int i=0; i < digits.size(); i++) 
    {
        if (number == digits[i]) cout << i << endl;
    }   


    if (number == "0")      cout << digits[0] << endl;
    else if (number == "1") cout << digits[1] << endl;
    else if (number == "2") cout << digits[2] << endl;
    else if (number == "3") cout << digits[3] << endl;
    else if (number == "4") cout << digits[4] << endl;  
    else if (number == "5") cout << digits[5] << endl;  
    else if (number == "6") cout << digits[6] << endl;  
    else if (number == "7") cout << digits[7] << endl;
    else if (number == "8") cout << digits[8] << endl;  
    else if (number == "9") cout << digits[9] << endl;  
}
```

digits is a vector class which stores the strings `"zero"`, `"one"` etc.

This code works fine but **I don't like** the long chain of `if/else if` statements but I can't figure out a way to convert the integers to strings. Can someone help me make this more efficient? Thanks!

Comment: "It doesn't look good" can be a argument, but runtime efficiency is not. Anything you do will be fast compared to the time taken by the I/O.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use that `if number == "0"` then `number[0] == '0'` which is `char`.

e.i instead if/else statements:

```
if (number[0] >= '0' && number[0] <= '9' )
  std::cout << digits[number[0] - '0'] << std::endl;
else
  std::cout << "wrong input - needs to be digit" << std::endl;
```

`string` is basically an array of characters, `std::string` is an array of characters of type `char`.
For instance these are two legimate ways to declare and initialize strings in c or c++

```
char s[3] = { '0', '1', '\0' }; 
char s[3] = "01";
```

Char value is technically integer (or rather byte) that stores the character code in some encoding (usually ASCII).
For instance the character code of **'0'** is **48**, that of **'1'** is **49**, **'2'** is **50**. And we use this, because we know that

```
'3' - '0' = 51 - 48 = 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I don't quite understand the idea behind `number-'0'` could you explain it a bit more? What is the program doing?

Comment: I added explanation to my post above

Comment: Oh, ok this makes sense I never viewed a string like that. Thanks for the explanation I will try to implement this.

Comment: I managed to implement the above along with the for loop i already had for outputting strings to integers. The only problem I have now is that when I enter numbers larger than 9 e.g. 10, 11 its outputs `"one"`, `"one"` according to the first char of the string :S How do i fix this?

Comment: that's a different problem then. number[0] - gets you only the first char in the string  (as if the first element in the array)
`"12"` - is an array of two elements (string of two chars), if you have entered 21 you'd have gotten two as a result because number[0] is '2'. You will need something like this: `int i; int result = 0; while (number[i] != '\0') { result = result * 10 + (number[i] - '0'); ++i; }

Answer (score 1):

You could do `digits[number[0] - 48]` to get rid of the if/else if.

Comment: Please...  `number[0] - '0'`.

Comment: @paddy What exactly is number[0]? I am not familiar with this concept. Are we defining a new vector class, number?

Comment: No, `number` is a string.  You can index individual characters in the string just like an array.  So `number[0]` is the first character.  When you subtract `'0'` from it, you convert an ASCII `0` value to a numeric `0` value.  You're saying that ASCII `0` is your base.  It's convenient that the number codes are arranged in order, as are the alphabetic characters.  This is a convenience that is frequently taken advantage of (*eg* sorting strings).

Comment: I should add that you want to make sure `number[0]` is in a valid range: `if (number[0] >= '0' && number[0] <= '9') ...`

Answer (score 0):

Just use isdigit to check if it's 0-9 http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isdigit/

And if it is a digit you could convert it to an int using aoti http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/

and finally just say

```
cout << digits[aoti(number)];
```